# The provided API key is expired (for Directions API)

Tags: ios, api, google-maps

I have looked into the first 15 "similar questions" to my question and none resolved my issue. Sometimes, the error I am getting for the same API request is "`This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address {*ip_address*}, with empty referer`". I also searched for that and none of the solutions suggested helped in my case.

**My current situation**

- I am calling `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=MYKEY&some_other_params` in an iOS project
- I am using an API key that is restricted to a Bundle ID
- I have a list of items (let's refer to it as **location items**) that when clicked I call the Direction API to get route info
- I am getting the two errors I mentioned above interchangeably. That means sometimes I get the expired error and sometimes I get the IP error. I get the errors for the same location item.

**APIs enabled:**

- Directions API
- Geolocation API
- Maps SDK for iOS
- Geocoding API
- Places API

**The Bundle ID is not the problem**

I know that my Bundle ID is correct as I am using it with another service, which is Firebase. To eliminate the silly mistake of mistyping, I copied the same Bundle ID from my Firebase API credential. My API key for Firebase is restricted to the same Bundle ID and to the Firebase service. It is working without any issues.

**API restrictions only**

To eliminate the Bundle ID issue, I also tried **None** for the *Application restrictions* and chose to restrict APIs. I added the APIs I listed above one at a time and called the Directions API. Nothing worked, neither having a single API (Directions API) or having all of them.

**The weird thing about Places API**

A weird behavior I am getting is that I created a new API key and it worked without any restrictions. What is more weird is that I disabled Places API temporarily. I did this as I wanted to "refresh" my APIs. I read in another thread that the IP issue was resolved by disabling and re-enabling the Places API.So I turned it off but did not turn it on immediately. I used a new API key and clicking my location items yields to route info (I got the desired result).

**Other restrictions (usage limit and billing)**

I know that it is also not about the restriction of too many attempts on the Directions API. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing) states that the limit is 50 requests per second. Besides, I did the "fast clicking of items" using the *unrestricted API key* and I always get a route info. Billing is also enabled on our project so that's not the issue either.

**Stuck with an *unrestricted key***

Right now we are using an unrestricted key that is unacceptable. I wonder, why using an unrestricted key works perfectly and restricting it does not. I am sure I am missing a configuration but I have tried every possible combination that I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

API keys restricted to your application's bundle ID won't work for backend web service requests such as Directions API. These API keys would only work for request made from Places SDK and Maps SDK for iOS. This is the reason why you are getting the error "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address {*ip_address*}, with empty referer".

According to Google Maps [API key best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices), for API keys used for Web services sent directly from a mobile applications, you can do one or more of the following techniques to secure your API keys:

- **Use a proxy server.** The proxy server provides a solid source for interacting with the appropriate Google Maps Platform API. Then restrict your API key with IP restrictions.
- **Obfuscate or encrypt the API key or signing secret.** This complicates scraping of API keys and other private data directly from the application.
- **Use CA pinning or certificate pinning to verify the server resources are valid.** CA pinning checks that a server's certificate was issued by a trusted certificate authority, and prevents Man-In-The-Middle attacks that could lead to a third party discovering your API key.